# How to set EditTextBox into edit mode by program code?

Tags: java, gwt

I'm using `GWT` with a `EditTextCell`, which goes into edit mode on click.
Does anybody know a way of forcing the box into edit mode by program code?

Would I have to somehow fire a `ClickEvent` onto that box? Or how could this be done?

Comment: edittextbox ?? or edittextcell  ??

Comment: Sorry, you're right I meant edittextcell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I can fire a native click event on my cell as follows:

```
NativeEvent nativeevent = Document.get().createClickEvent(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false);
cell.getElement().dispatchEvent(nativeevent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following method to your CellTable or DataGrid:

```
public void focus(final int row, final int column) {
    Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {

        @Override
        public void execute() {
            getRowElement(row).getCells().getItem(column).getFirstChildElement().getFirstChildElement().focus();
        }
    });
}
```

Then you can simple call `.focus(row, column)` when you need to set focus on a given cell.

Or you can call `.getRowElement()...` directly, but I recommend wrapping it in a ScheduledCommand so it does not fire too early - before the cell is ready to accept focus.

Comment: I'm just using `EditTextCell`, neither `CellTable` nor `DataGrid`! Just `EditTextCell` inside a `CellWidget`. So there is probably no `focus()` method to call...

Comment: There is a `.focus()` method on every element that can accept focus, including all input elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write `render` event or can add `clickHandler` for setting the `contentEditable=true` or `false`.

```
private class CustomEditCell extends EditTextCell {

        public void render(com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context context, String value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {

            sb.appendHtmlConstant("<div contentEditable='true' unselectable='true' >"+value+"</div>");  

         }
    }
```